# Blender as a Python Module Mac

Tags: python, module, cmake, compilation, blender

I've been following [this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117200/how-to-build-blender-as-a-python-module?answertab=votes#tab-top) on how to build blender as a python module. I am current working on a Mac. I've successfully got the source from Git, but I'm stuck trying to edit the CMake parameters. The manual says the following:

[image]

The first thing I tried was running `cmake ../blender`, editing the `~/blender-git/build/CMakeCache.txt` file, and running `make` (first option). But I got the following error:

[image]

The second thing I tried was setting the parameters on the command line (last option), but when the `~/blender-git/build/CMakeCache.txt` file was generated, the options I had entered were not actually changed.

If I run `cmake` and `make` without changing any parameters, everything works perfectly. I must be doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, paste the **error message as a text**, not as an *image* containing the text. It is strange that with near 1k reputation you are not aware about that requirement of Stack Overflow. Also, you talk about changes in `CMakeCache.txt` or parameters in the command line, but do not say what **exact** changes you have made or which parameters you have passed to `cmake`.

Comment: In `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions` what versions do you have, the current blender source requires python v3.7. Get the python 3.7 installer for OSX.